# WPF ComboBox...how to set the .Text property?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2008, combobox

Is there a way to set the `.Text` property of the Wpf ComboBox control directly?

My combobox is bound to a `List<T>` collection, but when I try to set `.Text` property in the `DropDownClosed` event, it totally ignores it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you're trying to set the text to the text of one of the items in the list it should work correctly.

If you're trying to set it to an item that isn't in the list then the IsEditable property needs to be true. You can set the IsReadOnly property to true if you don't actually want users typing into the combo box.

If none of these cases fit you, can you post the code you're using?

Comment: Thought I'd mention this as I just wasted a couple hours figuring it out. If the text you are trying to set is not on of the items in the list and you are using MultiBinding (i.e first + name name) and you set IsEditable="True" to make it work as Ray suggests when you select an item the text will display the Object Type (i.e. MY.Project.Person) instead of the proper text. I haven't come up with a solution yet.

Comment: @modernzombie: Override `ToString()` in the object.

Comment: @modernzombie Or, use ComboBoxItem, and set the Tag on the item to the actual object, and the content to the string you want to display.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try adding one more ComboBoxItem with Visibility=Collapsed, set that one as the selected item and set its content to whatever is needed.