# Binding a wpf combobox to an element

Tags: wpf, binding, combobox

A very basic question : I want to bind a wpf `ComboBox` to a selected element, so it displays the same value as the `TextBox`:

```
    <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding ElementName=comboBox1, Path=SelectedItem}">        
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Id}"></TextBox>
    <ComboBox ....
```

When changing the value of `combobox1`, the id of the selected item shows in the `TextBox`.  How do I bind a second `ComboBox` to the selected item in the first `ComboBox` to show the same value?

UPDATE : [WPF ComboBox…how to set the .Text property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895014/wpf-combobox-how-to-set-the-text-property) solved it for me : I needed the possibility to add items other than known beforehand, so the `IsEditable` property should have been true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WPF ComboBox…how to set the .Text property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895014/wpf-combobox-how-to-set-the-text-property) solved it for me : I needed the possibility to add items other than known beforehand, so the IsEditable property should have been true.

Answer (score 0):

Looks ok to me. Maybe you should post a more complete examole. Do you have [Selector.IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.issynchronizedwithcurrentitem.aspx) set on the combobox?